# Ajax Flexcroll with JQuery Mobile not loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm using Flexcroll and I got problem with Ajax.

I have Index.html and page1.html  and I put scroll code in Page1.html .When I open link from index.html it not working until I refresh the page.So please any help to fix that.

I'm using JQuery Mobile in this transition between pages.

This is my scroll code:

```
<div id="mycustomscroll" class="flexcroll">
  <div class="myajaxcontent" >
        <img src="images/zzz.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us more code then this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried applying `fleXenv.updateScrollBars()` when ajax request is completed?

You need version 2.1.1 [or 2.0.0] to have updateScrollBars method.

Documentation here:
http://www.hesido.com/flexcroll/flexcroll-programming.htm#update

I used it like this:

```
$('.myajaxcontent').load('/Page1.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
    ...
    ...
    fleXenv.updateScrollBars();
}
```